# Limit the request size when using Guzzle / Goutte

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, goutte

I am looking to re-write a Python script I have which goes through a list of links and then extracts some days from the pages it gets.

One problem which comes up is if the link is an image or zip or even an ISO, I don't want to download that whole file. I can try and check extension, but that doesn't always work.

In my Python script I do two things.

- Once I connect to the site, I check the content type header. Python seems to be able to do this without downloading the whole file.
- Limit how much of the URL I download in my request to 150kb. Since I am just after HTML pages, this more then covers it.

I want to use Guzzle for this project, but looking over the docs I am not sure if this can be done.

My main issue is making sure I am not downloading ISO files or videos and using all the RAM or bandwidth.

Comment: What version of Guzzle are you using? Goutte 1.0.6 uses 3, later versions use at least 4. If you are on the earlier version, the `request.before_send` event might do it, in a plugin.

Comment: If anyone else is looking for this feature, it seems there are [some Guzzle events](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/docs/http-client/request.rst#events-emitted-from-a-request), in particular `curl.callback.progress`, that would be worth investigating. It looks like it needs a cURL option to be set for the event to fire during a download.

Comment: I think I have an untested solution for this, for Guzzle 3. If anyone wants it, ping me here so I can hurry up and test it, so it can be posted.

Answer (score 4):

From guzzle 6 documentation. `stream`: set to true to stream a response rather than download it all up-front.

You can use this feature to download only first 150 KB.

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->get($url, [
    'stream' => true,
]);
$body = $response->getBody();

$bytesRead = 0;
$dataRead = "";
while (!$body->eof()) {
    $data = $body->read(1024);
    $dataRead .= $data;
    $bytesRead += strlen($data);
    if($bytesRead >= 150*1024) {
        $body->close();
        throw new \Exception("exceeded download limit");
    }
}
```